# Javascript setTimeout Recursive

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Consider this :

```
function some_function(){
  axios.get(...)
  .then(x=>{//handle})
  .catch(e=>{//handle})
  .then(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      some_function();
    },5000);
}
```

I don't care aboout cancelation, I just care if this is gonna blow the stack up.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `await`?

Comment: Not just `setTimeout`, also the asynchronous network request and the promise `then` calls prevent this from blowing up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't cause the stack to grow. `setTimeout()` callback functions are called from the main event loop asynchronously, not from your function. Your function returns immediately after you make the `axios.get()` call (since that's also asynchronous, it doesn't wait for it, either).

Comment: I though so. But using console.trace(), traces all the way back to the first call. So that was my main concerne.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that function. Despite what MDN says, I think that's a trace of scopes, not stack frames. Closures allow scopes to persist after popping the stack.